# gunicorn returns same pid for different worker process

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how gunicorn manages its processes so I wrote the following code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
from time import sleep

app = FastAPI()
sleep_time = [5, 0]
global_var = 100
order_called = 0

@app.get('/test')
def test_handler(): 
    global global_var, order_called       
    order_called += 1
    local_order_called = order_called
    sleep(sleep_time[order_called - 1]) # doing some time consuming stuff here  
    global_var += 1
    return {"test": os.getpid(), "global_var": global_var, "order called": local_order_called}
```

And I started gunicorn with:

```
gunicorn -w 2 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker server:app --preload
```

The server is supposed to output: pid, 102, 1 and pid, 101, 2 for two consecutive requests - because it takes more time for worker #1 to finish.

I'm getting the correct output, but somehow the two pids returned are the same, which is very strange - this happens with or without the --preload.

Anyone can shed some lights on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the server should produce multiple PIDs? I don't see anything here that would fork another process. `os.getpid()` will return the same value each time if called by the server. Hope that helps!

Comment: If you have two workers, two simutaneous requests will be handled by these two workers. The reason why here we have the same pid is that - I realized later - uvicorn uses async worker rather than synced ones.